# how to use cartalyst sentinel permission check in laravel vue spa?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, laravel-authentication, cartalyst-sentinel

I am building a SPA with laravel and Vue js. For authentication, I have used cartalyst/sentinel package. I am facing a problem to implement permission check in frontend. In the backend I have checked for the permission with `Sentinel::hasAccess()` function. But in the frontend, I don't have any idea how can I check for permission. As I am using Vue SPA but they don't provide any helper function for SPA frontend.

Comment: Its not gonna work like that you should pass array of permission from backend and handle it in frontend

Comment: But it will slow the entire system to check each permission validity from backend. I am looking for something helper function like vuei18 with laravel lang class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return an array with all the permissions and save it in your vue state and then to verify a permission you could do the following:

```
<button v-if="permisions['user.delete']" >delete user</button>
```

Comment: That doesn't sound so good when you have hundreds of permissions, and when the permissions can be inherited from roles.